# Qt v6.5.2 QtMultimedia Low Bitrate Audio Distortion

Tags: qml, qtmultimedia

I have audio files with .wav extension in version 6.5.2. I create the MediaPlayer component and define AudioOutput in it. I put my file with .wav extension as the source. When I start it up, there is flickering and distortion in the sound. When I follow the progress of the sound using onPositionChanged, for example, if the time bar reaches the 20th second, the position of the sound is much further behind. During this process, the sound is distorted and flickering. When I try versions earlier than 6.5.2 or newer, this problem does not exist. The sound is working properly. But there are some elements that connect me to version 6.5.2.

I am having this problem because the bit rate of the audio file I use is low. There is no problem when I use higher bit rate audio files. This problem has been fixed in other versions.

```
MediaPlayer {
    id: audioPlayer
    source: "example.wav"
    audioOutput: AudioOutput { }
}
```

When I use SoundEffect, the sound works properly even though it has a low bit rate. However, there are no functions such as setPosition or instant position reading in SoundEffect.

Comment: Whenever you have issues with your source audio, try troubleshooting by transcoding to different audio codecs/formats. Not all audio codecs/formats are equal. Some trial & error, i.e. experimentation, is required. The tools I've used in this area are (1) Audacity, (2) ffmpeg.

Comment: @StephenQuan thanks for your answer. I did not see such a method during my research. Will I use this via C++ without creating a QML component? Are there any examples available?

Comment: These are applications you run to preprocess your audio before you use it in your Qt app

Comment: @StephenQuan Thanks. I will do more detailed research on the subject.